# Short Story. Man given exprimental drug which gives him perfect recall of his memories

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, drug

I think I read this in the 80s. It is a short story.

The protagonist is soon to be married. He works for a drug company. He is approached by researchers who also work at his company. They want him to be a human volunteer, to test a new drug to give him perfect recall of his entire life.

The drug works, but the man becomes arrogant and uses his new amazing memory in ways that upset just about everyone he interacts with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *[Lest We Remember](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lest_We_Remember)* by Isaac Asimov.

> John Heath is a "dead average" man working for Quantum Pharmaceuticals. Unhappy with his average position in the company and in life, he searches for a way to improve himself and at the same time impress his fiancée, Susan Collins. When researchers from Quantum give him the opportunity, he volunteers to be a test subject for a new drug that allows total memory recall.